# Time not being Inserted into database table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a web form I am trying to make in which one is able to fill out counseling information said person is receiving. I know how to get the time to work with text fields, but for some reason when I changed it to a drop menu and changed how it gets inserted into the database, it no longer works. Any ideas why? This is what the php looks like. looks like.

```
//if submit is pressed
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

                //Create empty error array
                $error = array();

                //Check for names
                if(empty($_POST['providerName'])) {
                    $error['providerName'] = 'Please enter your name';
                }

                if(empty($_POST['clientName'])) {
                    $error['clientName'] = 'Please select the client\'s name';
                }

                //Check for services
                if(empty($_POST['service'])) {
                    $error['service'] = 'Please select a service';
                }

                if(empty($_POST['receiverGroup'])) {
                    $error['receiverGroup'] = 'Please select who is receiving the service';
                }

                //Check for time
                if(empty($_POST['hours'])) {
                    $error['hours'] = 'Please enter a value for number of hours';
                }

                if(empty($_POST['minutes'])) {
                    $error['minutes'] = 'Please enter a value for number of minutes';
                }

                //Check for method
                if(empty($_POST['method'])) {
                    $error['method'] = 'Please select a method';
                }

                //If there are no errors
                if(sizeof($error) == 0) 

                    {

                    $i = 0;
                    $temp = $_POST['receiverGroup'];
                    foreach($temp as $each) {
                        if($i==0){
                            $receiver = $each;
                        }else{
                            $receiver = $receiver + " , " + $each;
                        }
                        $i++;
                    }

                    $elapsedTime = $_POST['hours'] + ($_POST['minutes']/60);



                    //Insert a record into the database
                    $query = "INSERT INTO dosage (
                        entry_id,
                        providerName,
                        clientName,
                        services,
                        receiver,
                        elapsedTime,
                        method,
                        activity_date
                    ) VALUES (
                        null,
                        '{$_POST['providerName']}',
                        '{$_POST['clientName']}',
                        '{$_POST['service']}',
                        $receiver,
                        $elapsedTime,
                        '{$_POST['method']}',
                        NOW()
                    )";

                    //echo $query;

                    mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($dbc)); 

                    /* $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($dbc)); */

                    //Display a confirmation
                    echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success\">Thank You. Your entry has been submitted.</div>";

                } else {

                        foreach($error as $value) 
                        {
                                echo "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">";
                                echo $value;
                                echo "</div>";
                        }
                }
            }
```

Here is the HTML

```
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 background"> 
            <label class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 color h4">Total Time Providing Services (Hours, Minutes)</label><br />
            <select name = "hours">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>

            <select name = "minutes">
                <option value=":00">:00</option>
                <option value=":01">:01</option>
                <option value=":02">:02</option>
                <option value=":03">:03</option>
                <option value=":04">:04</option>
                <option value=":05">:05</option>
                <option value=":06">:06</option>
                <option value=":07">:07</option>
                <option value=":08">:08</option>
                <option value=":09">:09</option>
                // ...
```

And the table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `dosage` 
( `entry_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`providerName` text NOT NULL, 
`clientName` text NOT NULL, 
`services` text NOT NULL,
 `receiver` text NOT NULL,
 `elapsedTime` text NOT NULL,
 `method` text NOT NULL, 
`activity_date` datetime NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`entry_id`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;
```

Comment: Why don't you use MySQL `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead of inserting `NOW()`?

Comment: PHP string concatenation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: `$_POST['minutes']` has `:` at the begining. You need to remove this before you can divide by 60.

Comment: Use `implode` to combine all the elements of `$_POST['receiverGroup']` into a string.

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code. First, and foremost, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks because you are concatinating values into your SQL query. Instead, you should use prepared statements with parameters.

On to your issue,

```
$elapsedTime = $_POST['hours'] + ($_POST['minutes']/60);
```

Your `minutes` variable looks like this: `:00` through `:09`, etc. You are attempting to divide a string (with the leading colon (`:`) by 60. Remove that colon.

Additionally, you are **adding** your values together, not concatenating. If you want to concatenate string, use a period (`.`) instead of the addition operator (`+`)

```
$elapsedTime = $_POST['hours'] . ($_POST['minutes']/60);
```

This still doesn't solve another problem you are running into - decimal results to your division. For example, if you pass in a `minute` value of `10` (assuming you stripped the leading colon), you now have (assuming hours is `01`)

```
$elapsedTime = "01" . ":" .  (10/60);
```

Your `elapsedTime` variable looks like: `01:0.16666666666667`. That's not valid.

The best option you have may be to modify your database structure itself. You could store the elapsed time as a simple integer and perform the required math to get the correct time in minutes before storing:

```
$elapsedTime = ($hours * 60) + $minutes;
```

This provides a simple numerical value that you can use to perform mathematical operations on within the database (ie `MAX()`, `MIN()`, `SUM()`). These can't be done with the `TEXT` data type. It also allows you to easily convert BACK to your HH:MM format by reversing the above formula:

```
$original_hours = (int)($elapsedTime / 60);
$original_min = $elapsedTime % 60;
```